# How to specify classpath ordering in Gradle

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I need to control the ordering of jars in the testRuntime configuration.

I must make sure that robolectric-x.x.jar comes before android.jar, or else I get the dreaded RuntimeException("Stub!").

How do I do that?

Comment: Does it say in the documentation that the robolectric jar has to come before android.jar on the classpath?

Comment: Yes it does. From the Robolectric home page:

"Troubleshooting

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

Make sure that robolectric and its dependencies appear before the Android API jars in the classpath."

Comment: It works in Eclipse, because one can explicitly control the ordering of the classpath there.

The Eclipse project was generated by Gradle.

Comment: You can solve it by order in gradle dependencies, but beware two rules of the higher priority! http://stackoverflow.com/a/38743046/715269

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my complete **build.gradle** for running Robolectric tests against my Android app, which uses RoboGuice:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

androidJar = new File(System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME'), '/platforms/android-7/android.jar')

configurations { robo }

dependencies {
    robo('com.pivotallabs:robolectric:1.0-RC1')
    testCompile('org.roboguice:roboguice:1.1.2')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.8.2')
    testCompile project (':app')
    testCompile files(androidJar)
}

sourceSets.test.compileClasspath = configurations.robo + sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath = configurations.robo + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

test {
    excludes = ['**/MyRobolectricTestRunner.class']
}
```

I had to add an exclusion for the test runner, or else Gradle will throw an exception.

**MyRobolectricTestRunner.java** looks like this:

```java
package com.acme.myapp;

import java.io.File;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import roboguice.application.RoboApplication;
import roboguice.inject.ContextScope;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.Robolectric;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

public class MyRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public MyRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        // Tell Robolectric where to find AndroidManifest.xml and res/
        super(testClass, new File("../app"));
    }

    /**
     * Enable injection into tests as well...
     */
    @Override
    public void prepareTest(Object test) {
        RoboApplication myApplication = (RoboApplication) Robolectric.application;
        Injector injector = myApplication.getInjector();
        ContextScope contextScope = injector.getInstance(ContextScope.class);
        contextScope.enter(myApplication);
        injector.injectMembers(test);
    }

}
```

And here's a sample test that illustrates injection:

```java
package com.acme.myapp;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import roboguice.inject.InjectResource;

@RunWith(MyRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class StringFormattingTest {

    @InjectResource(R.string.info_pending_amount)
    private String pendingAmountPattern;

    @Test
    public void testFormatInfoPendingAmount() {
        String s = String.format(pendingAmountPattern, 20.0d, "EUR");
        assertEquals("Only a part of your stake (20,00 EUR) was accepted", s);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you reference your :app? via its own settings.gradle? Does the :app also expose its own dependencies for the tests to consume?

Comment: could we get a simple sample on github?

Answer (score 4):

This might work:

```
configurations { robo }

dependencies {
  robo ...
  testRuntime ...
}

sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath = configurations.robo + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
```

Comment: I had to add robo to the compileClasspath as well

Comment: @Peter Do you know how to [change the order of classpaths in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863845/how-to-configure-the-order-of-libraries-in-the-classpath-for-android-studio) ...