# TestCompile jar using environment variable

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to load the Android jar as a test dependency in a Java Gradle project. When I hardcode the path to the jar, everything works fine and the jar gets picked up:

```
testCompile files('/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar')
```

However, I don't want to rely on this absolute path, but rather use an environment variable. Unfortunately the following doesn't work - the Android classes are not available:

```
testCompile files((System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME') + '/platforms/android-22/android.jar'))
```

To verify that the path is correct, the following prints `/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar`:

```
println (System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME') + '/platforms/android-22/android.jar')
```

And the following prints `true`:

```
println new File((System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME') + '/platforms/android-22/android.jar')).exists();
```

---

Why is there a difference between the first and second method, and how can I make the second method work?

Comment: Generally your code is supposed to work. Can you run the next snippet to make sure your code maps to the right location: `project.configurations.testCompile.dependencies.all { d ->
    if (d instanceof FileCollectionDependency) {
        for (File fcd : d.resolve()) { println fcd}
    } 
}
`

Comment: So I guess this is the reason why the file is not found. I guess that the next question would be what causes this whitespace... BTW, have you also tried doing the following: `testCompile files(new File(System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME'), '/platforms/android-22/android.jar'))`? There is a chance that the constructing the file object this way will overcome the mysterious whitespace issue

Comment: Oh hold on, the whitespace was my fault, overlooked it (It's late :) ). Running your snippet prints `/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar` like it should. The problem persists though.

Comment: I know that this is a long shot, but I'm curious whether there's some logic that during dependency resolution tries to splits a paths containing `id`... Can you try to rename the `android-22` part to something else and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Ok - no more guesses for now.

Comment: Could you try it like it was done in this SO answer [how-to-specify-classpath-ordering-in-gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228076/how-to-specify-classpath-ordering-in-gradle#7281162)

Comment: @SubOptimal Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The snippet by Amnon prints out the correct location again, but I cannot reference the Android classes.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Are you able to strip down the problem and post the code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SubOptimal I just found out that in fact IntelliJ is not picking up the correct environment variable. Throwing an exception in the `build.gradle` file with the path as message shows `null/platforms/...`. I executed the print statements from the command line, which do work. I'll have a look into this now.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that in fact IntelliJ did not pick up my `ANDROID_HOME` env variable correctly. My environment variables were stored in a `~/.env` file, which got loaded by `~/.bashrc`. I moved the loading to the `~/.profile` file, and now IntelliJ does pick up the variable correctly, solving the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the solution. It was a simple reason but not easy to spot. ;-)